# SQL - Overall average Points

Tags: sql, sum, distinct, average

I have a table like this:

```
[challenge_log]
User_id   |    challenge  |  Try   |   Points
==============================================
  1               1           1            5
  1               1           2            8
  1               1           3            10
  1               2           1            5
  1               2           2            8
  2               1           1            5
  2               2           1            8
  2               2           2            10
```

I want the overall average points. To do so, i believe i need 3 steps:

Step 1 - Get the MAX value (of points) of each user in each challenge:

```
User_id   |    challenge  |  Points
===================================
  1               1           10
  1               2           8
  2               1           5
  2               2           10
```

Step 2 - SUM all the MAX values of one user

```
User_id   |  Points
===================
  1           18
  2           15
```

Step 3 -  The average

```
AVG = SUM (Points from step 2) / number of users = 16.5
```

Can you help me find a query for this?

Comment: What queries are currently being tried? Use a GROUP BY (on two columns) and an aggregate to get to Step #1. Use a GROUP BY (on one column of the previous result) and an appropriate aggregate to come up with the result-set in Step #2. Use an aggregate to come up with Step #3 (there is no grouping).

Comment: Or you could just use `Avg()` with a `Group By`

Comment: @user2864740 Ah, you're right, missed that bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the overall average by dividing the total number of points by the number of distinct users.  However, you need the maximum per challenge, so the sum is a bit more complicated.  One way is with a subquery:

```
select sum(Points) / count(distinct userid)
from (select userid, challenge, max(Points) as Points
      from challenge_log
      group by userid, challenge
     ) cl;
```

You can also do this with one level of aggregation, by finding the maximum in the `where` clause:

```
select sum(Points) / count(distinct userid)
from challenge_log cl
where not exists (select 1
                  from challenge_log cl2
                  where cl2.userid = cl.userid and
                        cl2.challenge = cl.challenge and
                        cl2.points > cl.points
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, it works!
That was really helpfull ;)

Comment: What if i want to count the users with 10 points in challenge 1?

Comment: The answer that you accepted has syntactically incorrect queries.

Answer (score 1):

Try these on for size.

- **Overall Mean**

  ```
  select avg( Points ) as mean_score
  from challenge_log
  ```
- **Per-Challenge Mean**

  ```
  select challenge ,
         avg( Points ) as mean_score
  from challenge_log
  group by challenge
  ```

If you want to compute the mean of each users highest score per challenge, you're not exactly raising the level of complexity very much:

- **Overall Mean**

  ```
  select avg( high_score )
  from ( select user_id   ,
                challenge ,
                max( Points ) as high_score
         from challenge_log
       ) t
  ```
- **Per-Challenge Mean**

  ```
  select challenge ,
         avg( high_score )
  from ( select user_id   ,
                challenge ,
                max( Points ) as high_score
         from challenge_log
       ) t
  group by challenge
  ```

Answer (score 0):

After step 1 do

```
SELECT USER_ID, AVG(POINTS)
FROM STEP1
GROUP BY USER_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine step 1 and 2 into a single query/subquery as follows:

```
    Select BestShot.[User_ID], AVG(cast (BestShot.MostPoints as money))
    from (select tLog.Challenge, tLog.[User_ID], MostPoints = max(tLog.points) 
            from dbo.tmp_Challenge_Log tLog
            Group by tLog.User_ID, tLog.Challenge
        ) BestShot
    Group by BestShot.User_ID
```

The subquery determines the most points for each user/challenge combo, and the outer query takes these max values and uses the AVG function to return the average value of them.  The last Group By tells SQL to average all the values across each User_ID.